# End of life date for Redis 3.0.5

Tags: redis

What is the expiry date / end of life date for Redis 3.0.5?

Is there any official document announcing the end of life date for Redis 3.0.5?

Answer (score 0):

according to [Redis release cycle](https://redis.io/topics/releases)

> Older versions are not supported as we try very hard to make the Redis
> API mostly backward compatible. Upgrading to newer versions is usually
> trivial.
>
> For example, if the current stable release is 2.6.x, we accept bug
> reports and provide support for the previous stable release (2.4.x),
> but not for older ones such as 2.2.x.
>
> When 2.8 becomes the current stable release, the 2.6.x will be the
> oldest supported release.

Since redis ver 6.0.* is the latest version today, and the previous stable release is 5.0.* then any previous version is no longer supported